# Pandas combining keys when grouping by multiple column

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy

I have 3 levels of grouping based on 3 keys: key1, key2, key3
I want to get the sum of a column (c1) for the following combination:

```
key1, sum(c1)
key1, key2, sum(c1)
key1, key2, key3, sum(c1)
```

I am getting the sums in 3 different dfs. (sum_k1, sum_k1k2, sum_k1k2k3)
I want to combine the dataframe and thereupon convert it to json as follows:

```
{
 key1: { 
          sum: x1,
          key2: {
                   sum: x2,
                   key3: {
                           sum: x3
                         }
                 }
         }
}
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way to go about it, but this is what I came up with

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# Prepare the sample dataset

table = []
for i in range(100000):
    row = {'key1': random.choice('ABC'),
           'key2': random.choice('KLM'),
           'key3': random.choice('XYZ'),
           'val' : random.randint(0,500)}
    table.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(table)

# Aggregate the first level

dict_agg = (df.groupby('key1')
            .sum()
            .rename(columns={'val':'sum'})
            .to_dict('index'))

# Convert from numpy.int64 to Python scalar
for idx, value in dict_agg.items():
    dict_agg[idx]['sum'] = int(dict_agg[idx]['sum'])

# Aggregate the second level

df_lvl2 = (df.groupby(['key1','key2'])
           .sum()
           .rename(columns={'val':'sum'})
           .to_dict('index'))

# Assign the second level aggregation

for idx, value in df_lvl2.items():
    dict_agg[idx[0]][idx[1]] = {'sum': int(value['sum'])}

# Aggregate the final level

df_lvl3 = (df.groupby(['key1','key2','key3'])
           .sum()
           .rename(columns={'val':'sum'})
           .to_dict('index'))

# Assign the third level aggregation

for idx, value in df_lvl3.items():
    dict_agg[idx[0]][idx[1]][idx[2]] = {'sum': int(value['sum'])}
```

The end result will look like this:

```
{'A': {'K': {'X': {'sum': 929178},
   'Y': {'sum': 940925},
   'Z': {'sum': 938008},
   'sum': 2808111},
  'L': {'X': {'sum': 902581},
   'Y': {'sum': 953821},
   'Z': {'sum': 942942},
   'sum': 2799344},
  'M': {'X': {'sum': 930117},
   'Y': {'sum': 929257},
   'Z': {'sum': 910905},
   'sum': 2770279},
  'sum': 8377734},
 'B': {'K': {'X': {'sum': 888818},
…
```

As this is a `dict`, you need to convert it to json, by doing:

```
import json
output = json.dumps(dict_agg)
```

Comment: Because I have multiple columns to sum. In the sum part I'm doing this. For the 1st level: `df.groupby('key1')['col1'].sum()`. to_dict('index') fails.

Comment: . the rename bit fails. The `to_dict('index')` also fails. `.to_dict()` works though.

Answer (score 0):

I used multilevel index for this and xs for this one.
Get the lowest level aggregates.

```
lvl3_grp = df.groupby(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])['col1', 'col2'].sum()
lvl3_grp = lvl3_grp.reset_index()
lvl3_grp.set_index(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], inplace=True)

res = {}
for k1 in lvl3_grp.index.levels[0]:
 sums = lvl3_grp.xs(k1).sum()
 lvl2_grp = lvl3_grp.xs(k1).reset_index()
 lvl2_grp.set_index(['key2', 'key3'], inplace=True)
 lvl2_dict = {}
 for k2 in lvl2_grp.index.levels[0]:
   sums = lvl2_grp.xs(k1).sum()
```

For the last level `.index.levels[0]` wont work as its single index. I used `.index.values` for iterable list and `.loc` inside the for loop for accessing the values.

I'll expand the answer at a later time.